# Duplicate error message when error handling

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procA (paramA VARCHAR2, paramB VARCHAR2, output_value OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    IF paramA IS NOT NULL THEN
        BEGIN --1
            SELECT columA
              INTO output_value
              FROM tableA
             WHERE columnB = paramA;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                -- 2
                SELECT columB
                  INTO output_value
                  FROM tableB
                 WHERE columnC = paramB;
        END;
    ELSE
        SELECT columB
          INTO output_value
          FROM tableB
         WHERE columnC = paramB;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20008, 'Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END procA;
```

I run this call:

```
DECLARE
    output   VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN
    procA ('valueA', 'valueB', output);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM); --3
END;
```

With these parameters the first `SELECT` statement gets a `NO_DATA_FOUND` (1). And handled with the that EXCEPTION. Then, I run the second `SELECT` statement (2) and I get again, a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.
Why do I get a duplicate `NO_DATA_FOUND` message in (3), like this:

```
ORA-20008: Error: 100 ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
```

The first exception is handled, I expected that the last error handling will return just one message.

Comment: cause there is no data for both selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't seeing a single error being duplicated; you're seeing two errors, which happen to be the same.

If you add a `format_error_stack` call to your final exception hander you can see that both of the thrown exceptions are in that stack:

```
...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20008, 'Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 200));
END procA;
/
```

The call from your anonymous block then shows:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "<schema>.PROCA", line 13
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "<schema>.PROCA", line 6

ORA-20008: Error: 100 ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0fcdc9ffd72c8549cf9317358705c76e)

It might be a bit clearer if you vary the errors, e.g.:

```
declare
  l_dummy varchar2(1);
begin
  begin
    select 'x' into l_dummy from all_users;
  exception when too_many_rows then
    select 'x' into l_dummy from all_users where 1=0;
  end;
exception when others then
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
  dbms_output.put_line('caught <' || sqlerrm || '>');
end;
/
```

which produces:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 5

caught <ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows>
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0fcdc9ffd72c8549cf9317358705c76e)

The SQLERRM call combines both error messages, though [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SQLERRM-function.html) doesn't seem to say that will happen. Oracle support note 2438311.1 seems to suggest it shouldn't, but it does all of the db<>fiddle versions and in 12.2.0.1 and 19.11 at least.

---

> But, what if I just want the last one?

If you're on Oracle 12c or later, you can use `UTL_CALL_STACK.ERROR_MSG(1)` to get the first error from the stack, instead of using `SQLERRM`.

```
...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20008,
            'Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SUBSTR (UTL_CALL_STACK.ERROR_MSG(1), 1, 200));
END procA;
/
```

which will now just show:

```
ORA-20008: Error: 100 no data found
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=39a0a6b98f44b3ecac2a192854a9c7c3) (and [another one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6f6782efacd78f935ab9f312083feeed) for my earlier example.)

You can read more about that function [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_CALL_STACK.html#GUID-BEFC0087-DB17-4C33-9730-F5BC1984B156).

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between handling and catching an exception.
You're using `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`, which throws the exception to the caller although you've caught it once and since you catch it two times - you have two errors.

Comment: But, what if I just want the last one? I have tried to put 'FALSE' in the last parameter in 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR' to replace all previous errors. But doesn't work.

Comment: You can remove the exception handling that is raising in the procedure or just to the error handling there. If you can do a proper error handling in the procedure - do it there, in general, when you handle exceptions you throw them if you can't handle them in the current scope and only option is to escalate to the caller.